# How to write conditionally odoo domain?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

I want to apply a odoo domain if the a field is not False.

```
['|',('versions_ids', '=', version_id),(False, '=', version_id)]
```

The domain like I wrote throw this error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

EDIT:

The object extend:

```
class sale_order_line(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    version_id = fields.Many2one('product_cars_application.version',string='Version')
```

the view extend

```
<record id="sale_cars_append" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                    <script type='text/javascript' src='/product_cars_application/static/src/js/filter.js'></script>
                </xpath>

                <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[1]/field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="before">
                    <!-- <button name="product_search" type="action" class="oe_highlight" icon="fa-car" /> -->
                    <field name="version_id"/>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[1]/field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name = "domain">['|',('versions_ids', '=', version_id),(False, '=', version_id)]</attribute>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: If you would not mind providing more context. Show the code where your domain is defined (not just the domain). Show the field definition which calls your function.

Comment: @Phillip Stack edit adding context

Comment: I have seen something like this. version_ids is a list, version_id is an int or False. The list int comparison is probably an issue. Wrap `version_id` in a list `('versions_ids', '=', [version_id])

Comment: also use `in` instead of `=`

Comment: the first part of the domain works ok. ('versions_ids', '=', version_id).
but if I only use this if version_id is False, it only shows the products with versions_ids = False, and I want to show all

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[1]/field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name = "domain">['|',('version_ids', '=', version_id),('version_ids','=',False),'|',('version_id','=',False)]</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Comment: the first part of the domain works ok. ('versions_ids', '=', version_id).
but if I only use this if version_id is False, it only shows the products with versions_ids = False, and I want to show all

Comment: I will amend my suggestion.

Comment: I often find these domains a non intuitive process. I think if you place the `OR` operator in front of the first tuple the parser expects the second tuple to be an alternate value of the first leaf in the first tuple. So you probably want to place the `|` after your first tuple.

Answer (score 0):

This should be like this,

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[1]/field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name = "domain">['|',('version_ids', '=', version_id),('version_ids','=',False)]</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Another option for domain.

```
['|',('version_ids', '=', version_id),('version_ids','=',[(6,False,[])])]
```

Comment: That would show products with sales.order.line.version_id is in sales.order.line.product_id.versions_ids and also sales.order.line.product_id.versions_ids = False ... I need to show:

If "version_id" not False show "sales.order.line.version_id" is in "sales.order.line.product_id.versions_ids"

Comment: And what if version id is false ?

Comment: I need to apply the domain, only if version_id is not false.
In python would be.
if version_id:
    domain = [('version_ids', '=', version_id)]
else:
    domain = []

Your code if version_id is defined, show products which versions_ids = False, and I need to only shows products which product_id.versions_ids = version_id